# Recursive function sum value not resetting to zero. Why?

Tags: recursion, computer-science

This code works. What I can't understand is how the value of `sum` keeps growing. Each recursive iteration it would seem should reset the value to 0, but it doesn't. Why?

```
const array = [[[2]], 1, [1, 3]];
function nestedAdd(array) {
  let sum = 0; <--- Why doesn't this keep resetting to 0?
  
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const currentValue = array[i];
    if (Array.isArray(currentValue)) {
      sum += nestedAdd(currentValue);
    } else {
      sum += currentValue;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

I'd expect the let sum = 0; to reinitialize the variable at a value of 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a different incarnation of `sum` in every execution of `nestedAdd()`. In the first, top-level call, that `sum` adds up 2, 1, and 4. The next, different `sum` in the first second-level call, as well yet another `sum` in a third-level call from there both add up a single 2. Then another second-level call with the fourth incarnation of `sum` adds up 1 and 3.

Comment: I think I get it now after thinking about it more. Each sum variable returns its value to the calling function, and that continues up the chain until we get to the first function. Then sum is set to the final value of the nested sum value, however deep that recursion goes.

Comment: Correct.........

Answer (score 0):

Initializing the value of sum = 0 has no effect here. sum is a local variable to the function, meaning, each time the function is called, it is always a new sum (variable) available within that call of the function. And finally, yes you are preventing it from being ZERO because you are returning the calculated total value as sum as the return value, so basically, with each call, nested call, you are adding the called sum to the caller sum.

Guess this helps.

Comment: Has no effect? That depends on the language, which was not specified. Also being explicit about initializing a sum to zero has an effect on the _reader_. Programs are not just specifications for compilers. They are also literature for humans.

Comment: Please forgive me, I am sorry. It has serious effect.